# Where can I find a full distribution of FAR Manager (plugins bundle)?

Tags: windows, file-management, far-manager

[FAR Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/download.php) is a very powerful open-source file manager for Windows. Most of its qualities are coming from the plugins but the official distribution is missing them.

I'm looking for an updated bundle that should contain the most important FAR Manager plugins:

- [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) - SCP/FTP file transfer
- [Colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/farplugin.html) - syntax highlighting
- [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) - support to archive in Zip and 7-Zip and unarchive almost any format
- [Picture View 2](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/downloads/list) - View pictures using F3, no external viewer needed.
- [ConEMU](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/downloads/list) - for additional console support including resize support.

Comment: Well, I learned something today: [Orthodox file Managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager#Orthodox_file_managers)

Answer (score 3):

There are several Far Manager bundles here and there and they basically all show lack of practical usefulness for a particular user, especially a power one. The Far Group team, as far as I know, is very sceptical about bundles, too. The Far Manager philosophy is "learn, collect and configure everything yourself". This approach takes time but it is proven to be the best.

It is almost impossible to choose a reasonably good subset from several hundred existing plug-ins that will be suitable for many users. For example, you provided a good subset but personally I use only Colorer and 7-zip support of it. On the other hand, I use a few must-have plug-ins that are not in your list.

Then, the most interesting important plug-ins and Far Manager itself are being actively developed. Improvements and bug fixes are quite frequent. The task of keeping a hypothetical ideal bundle up-to-date is difficult and time consuming. A few existed bundles got staled and abandoned very quickly.

Thus, I would recommend you to not count on or follow any bundles. Instead, subscribe to news of development sites that you mentioned and keep your favourite stuff updated yourself. Also, subscribe to the "Plug-in Announcements" Far Manager forum:

http://forum.farmanager.com/viewforum.php?f=11

In particular, you may find there recent updates of Colorer and a new very promising 7-zip plug-in "arclite".

Technically this forum is in Russian but some of announcements are still in English and you can use some web translator, too (it's not perfect but readable enough). There are also sections for English speaking users, if you have questions/problems do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Maybe offtopic, but FAR team also has the habit of writing code comments in Russian.

Comment: That is probably true but don’t forget that significant amount of code was written long time ago when the product was not open source and English was/is not necessarily fluent for some of Far developers and contributors. I believe it’s not a real obstacle for those who want to contribute. (This is off topic, indeed.)

Comment: Thanks Roman, one remark: I can assure you that Russian language is a real obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

The bundle with the required plug-ins is recently created:
http://dj-andrey.ru/soft/far

`ConEmu` is not included. Technically speaking, it is not a plug-in for `Far Manager`.